# laravel return view check available

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I'm working with laravel 5.6 to build my app.

When I visit the / my controller gets me an array of services like

```
        @foreach($servicies as $service)
            <div class="col-sm-4 wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
                <a href="{{url("servicios/{$servicie->id}/{$service->name}")}}/">
                    <div class="service-icon">
                        <i class="fa fa-{{$service->icon}}"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="service-info">
                        <h3>{{$servicio->getAttribute('title-main')}}</h3>
                        <p class="btn-class">{{$servicio->getAttribute('text-main')}}</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        @endforeach
```

that `a` I have is a route, but I'm not building all the services.

So, I would like to know if with laravel is there any easy way to check if a services is available or not, without having to put an special field in the database to check it

like

```
if($service->available){
return view....
}else{
return 404
}
```

Comment: you mean that how to know if there are services in the database ??

Comment: the service is in the database, but when i access Ex: /service/1/clean the service clean will return a view, but when I access Ex: /service/2/dry don't, because I dont have the finromation to build it yet

Comment: i understand that availlibility of services depends of the company if that right then you must create that field but you can make the a tag for the unavailable services unclickebal so you don't need to check in the controller

Comment: yeah, I though the same but may be, just maybe laravel though that for us!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand you very well, but from your question, you can do this in your views to resolve your problem

```
@if($services->count())
     @foreach($servicies as $service)
    <div class="col-sm-4 wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
        <a href="{{url("servicios/{$servicie->id}/{$service->name}")}}/">
            <div class="service-icon">
                <i class="fa fa-{{$service->icon}}"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="service-info">
                <h3>{{$servicio->getAttribute('title-main')}}</h3>
                <p class="btn-class">{{$servicio->getAttribute('text-main')}}</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
@endforeach
@else
   <div class="alert alert-warning">No service available at this moment</div>
@endif
```

Comment: Please post code if Services model and controller in which you are accessing Services model.

Answer (score 0):

```
@if(!empty($services)
    @foreach($servicies as $service)
        <div class="col-sm-4 wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
            <a href="{{url("servicios/{$servicie->id}/{$service->name}")}}/">
                <div class="service-icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-{{$service->icon}}"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="service-info">
                    <h3>{{$servicio->getAttribute('title-main')}}</h3>
                    <p class="btn-class">{{$servicio->getAttribute('text-main')}}</p>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    @endforeach
@else
Display whatever you want here
@endif
```